# Specified font only applies after refresh in Next JS / Material UI

Tags: javascript, material-ui, next.js

When I'm redirected to a page, the font I specified in the CSS file only applies AFTER I manually refresh the page.

1. Click sign out (account.js)
2. Redirected to page to enter credentials (login.js)

I expect the font (in this case [Carter One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Carter+One)) to apply right away but instead I get the Railway default in "Successfully signed out".  I tried to debug by adding "This text in login" which is a `Typography` tag and "This text in p" which is a `p` tag.  `p` tag acts as expected but the top two texts will only join with the correct font on refresh.

[image]

I'm using Next JS with Material UI.

*Code snippets leave out imports.*

### login.js

```js
export default function Login() {
  const user = useUserContext()
  const router = useRouter()

  if (user) {
    router.push("/account")
  }

  return (
    <>
    {!user &&
      <BaseLayout hideLogin>
        <Box sx={{ mt: '3rem' }}>
          {byeMsg &&
            <Typography variant="h3" className={headerLogoAppBar}  <!-- utils.module.css -->
                        sx={{ mb: "3rem", textAlign: "center" }}>
                        Successfully signed out
            </Typography>
          }
          <Typography variant="h1" className={headerLogoAppBar}>This text in login</Typography>
          <p className={headerLogoAppBar}>This text in p</p>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={auth} />
          </Box>
      </BaseLayout>
    }
    </>
  )
}
```

### utils.module.css

```css
.headerLogoAppBar {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
}
```

### global.css

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

## What I've tried

- Linked Google Fonts as recommended in https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization

```js
  ...

  return(
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Carter+One&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet" />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

- Added `createTheme` in Next JS

**This actually worked but isn't ideal as the font I want applied to EVERYTHING and I can control CSS better.**

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      "Roboto",
      "Carter One",
      "-apple-system",
      "BlinkMacSystemFont"
    ].join(",")
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the font in your custom _document.js?

Comment: @whygee That's what `Linked Google Fonts as recommended in https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization` is.  I can confirm the import is working when looking at Chrome Dev Tools.